# EF Code First Fluent Mapping: 0-1 to Many: HasOptional(), same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent-nhibernate, ef-code-first, one-to-many

I have a "Category" Entity as follow:

```
 public class Category
 {
    //<Summary>
    //Fields...
    //</Summary>

    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public bool IsDelete { get; set; }

    // Fields for relationships
    public Guid MainCategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category MainCategory { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> ChildCategories { get; set; }
 }
```

As seen above I want to create 0-one-to-many relationship in same table. I used Fluent API for this as follows:

```
 HasRequired(category => category.MainCategory)
            .WithMany(category => category.ChildCategories)
            .HasForeignKey(category => category.MainCategoryId);
```

But it is a one-to-many, isn't 0-1-to-many. I use *HasOptional*, but it give me an error.

How can I do this with Fluent API?

*thanks for reply*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the `MainCategoryId` property nullable:

```
public Guid? MainCategoryId { get; set; }
```

And then you can use `HasOptional` method:

```
HasOptional(category => category.MainCategory)
            .WithMany(category => category.ChildCategories)
            .HasForeignKey(category => category.MainCategoryId);
```